# Is it possible to show an image with Yii CForm formbuilder?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cform

I'm looking for a easy way to show an image in a CForm formbuilder array.
But I want to show the model contents, something like this example:

```
array(
    'elements'=>array(
        '<img src="$this->thumbnail" />',
        'thumbnail'=>array(
            'type'=>'file',
        ),
    ),
)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I think there is no such option like your code. we need to pass it as `element`.

Comment: To bad, I was hoping there was some kind of eval or custom element type/class possible. Thanks anyway for your fast reply :)

Comment: you can set in title. `'title' =>'form title',`. i think you can place image instead of `form title` text

Comment: Yes, but I want a dynamic image, with src filled from it's model

Comment: did you try something like `'title'=>'<img src="'.$model->image_path.'">'` ?

Comment: Yes, but $model is not defined, but this works :)

`'<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$this->getModel()->thumb.'" alt="" />',`

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, this works.

```
return array(
    'elements'=>array(
        '<img src="'.$this->getModel()->thumbnail.'" alt="" />',
        'thumbnail'=>array(
            'type'=>'file',
        ),
    ),
);
```